# как получить все реализуемые классом интерфейсы Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

Есть несколько классов, реализующих интерфейсы. Нужно получить названия этих интерфейсов через ROSLYN

Comment: Roslyn для этого не нужен. Используйте рефлексию.

Comment: Автор, дополни свой вопрос. Что именно ты пытаешься сделать? Распарсить SyntaxTree и получить объявление интерфейса по заданному типу? В таком случае приведи пример рабочего кода, чтобы мы имели представление о том, каким API ты пользуешься.